# Discriminator column mapped as entity Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, entity, discriminator

In hibernate, is it possible to have discriminator as an entity? For example, if I have Department as the base class & AdminDepartment & ProcessingDepartment as subclasses. DepartmentType is the discriminator & is an entity mapped to DEPT_TYPE table.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible, though such a relationship will be read-only:

```
@Entity @Inheritence(...)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DEPT_TYPE_ID")
public class Department {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_TYPE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private DepartmentType deptType;
    ...
}
```