# Avoid repetition of @DiscriminatorValue jpa

Tags: java, jpa

When we deal with inheritance in JPA we have defined column `DTYPE` in database which distinguish subentities by @DiscriminatorColumn. Each value of that column(@DiscriminatorValue) is stored as VARCHAR in database. I think that it's a bit costly for memory, isn't it? If I'm right how to change this mechanism in way that value of `DTYPE` be only reference to column with predefined entries(names of each subclass).

Comment: Why do you think a class name would be less costly than another string? Why do you think a discriminator column is costly?

Comment: I think less costly would be to have distinct table with few rows, where were stored all possible values of `DTYPE`(for example table which called DTYPE_VALUES). And main table with column 'DTYPE' then just would reference to those values.

Comment: If I have the column order when `DTYPE` may be for example only `car` or `boat`. Does it have a sense to store up for example 100000 VARCHAR those 'car' or 'boat' instead just links ?

Comment: correct me if i wrong

Comment: There is no such thing as "references" in relational databases. If by "reference", you mean "a numeric foreign key to the primary key of another table", then use a numeric value, then use INTEGER or CHAR as the dicriminator type of the column. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html#discriminatorType%28%29

Comment: i think it could be columnDefinition. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discriminator column mapped as entity Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273975/discriminator-column-mapped-as-entity-hibernate)